# yq create complex object based on existing file

Tags: bash, docker-compose, yaml, yq

Given a docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  service1:
    image: image:name
    environment: 
      - TEMP_ID=1928
    volumes: 
      - type: bind
        source: local/path/to 
        target: container/path/to
    ports:
      - 8900:8580
  service2:
    image: image:name
    environment: 
      - TEMP_ID=1451
    volumes: 
      - type: bind
        source: local/path/to/1451
        target: container/path/to
    ports:
      - 8901:8580
```

I am limited to writing a bash script to add a service to the above template based on its content. some of the values are being directly copied from the last service written in the services array, some fields needs modification.
I managed to extract and prepare all the values I need to add and I am stuck with creating the service object and add it to the existing file.
The script I have so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVICE_NAME=$1
TEMP_ID_ARG=$2

#extract data to copy from last configured client.
SERVICES=($(yq eval '.services | keys' docker-compose.yml))
LAST_SERVICE=${SERVICES[${#SERVICES[@]}-1]}
echo "adding user based on last service: $LAST_SERVICE"

IMAGE=$(yq -P -C eval '.services["'$LAST_SERVICE'"].image' docker-compose.yml)

ENVIRONEMNT_ENTRY="TEMP_ID=${TEMP_ID_ARG}"

TARGET_PATH_IN_CONTAINER=$(yq -P -C eval '.services["'$LAST_SERVICE'"].volumes[0].target' docker-compose.yml)
VOLUME_TYPE=$(yq -P -C eval '.services["'$LAST_SERVICE'"].volumes[0].type' docker-compose.yml)

LOCAL_PATH_TO_SOURCES=$(yq -P -C eval '.services["'$LAST_SERVICE'"].volumes[0].source' docker-compose.yml)

PATH_AS_ARRAY=($(echo $LOCAL_PATH_TO_SOURCES | tr "\/" " ")) 
PATH_AS_ARRAY[${#PATH_AS_ARRAY[@]}-1]=$TEMP_ID_ARG

NEW_PATH_TO_RESOURCE=$(printf "/%s" "${PATH_AS_ARRAY[@]}")

# extract port mapping, take first argument (exposed port) increment its value by 1 (no upper limitation)
# join back together with : delimiter.
PORT_MAPING_AS_ARRAY=($(yq -P -C eval '.services["'$LAST_SERVICE'"].ports[0]' docker-compose.yml | tr ":" " "))
# NO UPPER LIMITATION FOR PORT!!!
PORT_MAPING_AS_ARRAY[0]=$(expr $PORT_MAPING_AS_ARRAY + 1)
NEW_PORT_MAPPING=$(printf ":%s" "${PORT_MAPING_AS_ARRAY[@]}")
NEW_PORT_MAPPING=${NEW_PORT_MAPPING:1}

VOLUME_ENTRY=$(yq -P -C eval --null-input '.type = "'$VOLUME_TYPE'" | .source = "'$NEW_PATH_TO_RESOURCE'" | .target = "'$TARGET_PATH_IN_CONTAINER'"')
test=$(yq -P -C -v eval --null-input ' .'$SERVICE_NAME'.image = "'$IMAGE'" | .'$SERVICE_NAME'.environement = ["'$ENVIRONEMNT_ENTRY'"] | (.'$SERVICE_NAME'.volumes = ["'$VOLUME_ENTRY'"] | .'$SERVICE_NAME'.ports = ["'NEW_PORT_MAPPING'"])')
echo $test
```

when running, what I thought to be a working assembly command of all parts, returns the following error:

> Error: cannot pass files in when using null-input flag

the expected output when calling `add_service.sh service3 1234`
given the above input file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  service1:
    image: image:name
    environment: 
      - TEMP_ID=1928
    volumes: 
      - type: bind
        source: local/path/to 
        target: container/path/to
    ports:
      - 8900:8580
  service2:
    image: image:name
    environment: 
      - TEMP_ID=1451
    volumes: 
      - type: bind
        source: local/path/to/1451
        target: container/path/to
    ports:
      - 8901:8580
  service3:
    image: image:name
    environment: 
      - TEMP_ID=1234
    volumes: 
      - type: bind
        source: local/path/to/1234
        target: container/path/to
    ports:
      - 8902:8580
```

As my bash skills are not so strong I welcome any advice or better solution to my problem.

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: `yq` depends on python.  Do not use Bash and `yq`.  Use python.

Comment: You gave input data, what's you expected output ?

Comment: @KamilCuk: "_yq is written in go"_

Comment: @philippe thanks for the comment, added expected output

Comment: @Fravadona that's a different problem there is https://github.com/kislyuk/yq that is on my archlinux, but for eample on Alpine linux there's https://github.com/mikefarah/yq that is written in go. They are different. Portability is hard. Well, unlress you just use Python or Perl or Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it all with one [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) call, passing the external values as variables; that will make the code **safer** and **faster**:

```sh
service_name="service3" \
temp_id="1234" \
environment="TEMP_ID=1234" \
yq eval '
    .services[ .services | keys | .[-1] ] as $last |
    .services[ strenv(service_name) ] = {
        "image": $last.image,
        "environment": [ strenv(environment) ],
        "volumes": [ {
            "type": $last.volumes[0].type,
            "source": (
                $last.volumes[0].source |
                split("/") | 
                .[-1] = strenv(temp_id) |
                join("/")
            ),
            "target": $last.volumes[0].target
        } ],
        "ports": [ (
            "" + $last.ports[0] |
            split(":") |
            .[0] tag = "!!int" |
            .[0] += 1 |
            join(":") |
            . tag = ""
        ) ]
    }
' docker-compose.yml
```

output:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  service1:
    image: image:name
    environment:
      - TEMP_ID=1928
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: local/path/to
        target: container/path/to
    ports:
      - 8900:8580
  service2:
    image: image:name
    environment:
      - TEMP_ID=1451
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: local/path/to/1451
        target: container/path/to
    ports:
      - 8901:8580
  service3:
    image: image:name
    environment:
      - TEMP_ID=1234
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: local/path/to/1234
        target: container/path/to
    ports:
      - 8902:8580
```

Comment: You're welcome, I updated the `yq` code to make it more robust. For example, should `.ports[0]` be `8901` instead of `8901:8580`, the previous code failed.